# Unwind then segue without showing intermediate view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue, unwind-segue

I have three `UIViewControllers` where A -> B -> C, and A -> D.

When the user is done in C I want to unwind back to A and then segue to D, but I cannot get this to work without briefly showing A before the segue to D happens. I have tried disabling the `animates` property for the segue but  A still flashes into view for less than a second.

Any idea as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Code in swift 3 :-

```
let oldVCs = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
var newVCs = [UIViewController]()

// Add your root VC in new array of VCs
newVCs.append(oldVCs![0])
// Add your new VC just after your root VC
newVCs.append("Your New VC")

self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(newVCs, animated: true)
```