# Xcode Swift perform segue with alert

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uialertaction

I have three ViewControllers. I want to perform a segue from the `ThirdViewController` to the `SecondViewController` when you click on the `Ok` Button of an alert showing up. I already tried with this code:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action -> Void in
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewControllerSegueBack", sender: self)
}))
```

The problem is that a new window of the `SecondViewController` shows up, so when I click `back` on the navigation bar it leads me back to the `ThirdViewController`. I want it to show the `FirstViewController`.

Comment: You need an unwind segue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Comment: Try this if it works in your scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792130/unwind-then-segue-without-showing-intermediate-view-controller/45792543#45792543

Comment: just have a look at this how-to: (unwind segues) https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/create-unwind-segues-in-swift-3-8793f7d23c6f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SecondViewController you must create the Unwind segue

```
@IBAction func unwindToController2(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

The on storyboard in ViewController3 drag from ViewController to exit Button and add segue. Add identifier to it, and call in UIAlertController[image]

Comment: @lolinger2001 You are welcome) Please check answer like correct)